# Manual Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was working on my website and I want this div that contains images inside of an unordered list and two divs to show one picture at a time when either their left or right div is clicked, you know sort of like a manual slide show. I think I am having a problem with the z-index because for some reason I do not think that I am allowed to click on the divs. Or it could be my JQuery. Please take a look and help me out.

HTML:

```
<div id="bottomLeft">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="image/10pc.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="slideImages/chicken0.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="slideImages/chicken1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="slideImages/chicken2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="leftArrow">left</div>
    <div id="rightArrow">right</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#rightArrow').click(function() {
    $('#bottomLeft li[visibility="visible"]').attr("visibility","hidden").next.attr("visibility","visible");
});
```

CSS:

```
#bottomLeft{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 25.9em;
    /*background-color: limegreen;*/
    top:0;
    /*background-image: url(image/10pc.jpg);*/
    position:relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
#bottomLeft ul li img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 25.9em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -5;
}
#bottomLeft ul li{
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#bottomLeft ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: -5;
}
#bottomLeft ul li:not(:first-child){
    visibility:hidden;
}
```